# Sie ist eine ganz liebe/Liebe und nette/Nette

Tags: capitalization

Sind die beiden Wörter gegen Ende des folgenden Satzes groß oder klein zu schreiben? Warum?:

> 1. Wenn man dem Erwin glauben darf, dann ist die Hanni eh eine ganz ***l***iebe und ***n***ette.
> 2. Wenn man dem Erwin glauben darf, dann ist die Hanni eh eine ganz ***L***iebe und ***N***ette.

**Kontext:**

Der Satz stammt aus einem Kommentar-Dialog auf Facebook.

- »Der Erwin« ist Erwin Pröll, Landeshauptmann des Bundeslandes Niederösterreich, der vor zwei Tagen nach 25 Jahren Amtszeit seinen Rücktritt angekündigt hat. (Ein österreichischer *Landeshauptmann* hat dieselbe Funktion wie ein deutscher Ministerpräsident. Die Bezeichnung hat nichts mit militärischen Dienstgraden zu tun, sondern ist ein ziviles politisches Amt.)
- »Die Hanni« ist Johanna Mikl-Leitner, die seine Nachfolgerin werden wird. Sie war bis vor ca 1/2 Jahr die Innenministerin Österreichs, und fiel in dieser Funktion eher mit einer harten Haltung auf.
- Die Facebook-Diskutanten sind lauter Österreicher, daher entspricht die Grammatik der österreichischen Umgangssprache (Namen werden mit vorangestellten Artikeln verwendet; Der Satz enthält die Partikel »eh«, die sich in den letzten Jahrzehnten aber ohnehin bereits schon weit nach Deutschland ausgebreitet hat).

Es geht aber nicht um die regionalen Variationen des Satzbaues, sondern um die Groß- oder Kleinschreibung von »liebe« und »nette«.

Ich bitte darum, die Antwort auch zu begründen.

---

### Nachtrag (Reaktion auf einen Kommentar)

Als Argument für die Kleinschreibung wurde angeführt, dass man den Satz mit »Frau« ergänzen könnte:

> Die Hanni ist eine ganz liebe und nette *Frau*.

Das überzeugt mich aber nicht, denn ich kann auch mit »Mensch« oder »Mädchen« ergänzen. Nur muss ich dann das Geschlecht des Artikels und der beiden Adjektive ändern:

> Die Hanni ist ein- ganz liebe**r** und nette**r** *Mensch*.
>   Die Hanni ist ein- ganz liebe**s** und nette**s** *Mädchen*.

Ohne dieses hinzugefügte Substantiv hängt das Geschlecht von Artikel und Adjektiven aber ausschließlich vom Subjekt ab:

> Der Robert ist ein- ganz l/Liebe**r** und n/Nette**r**.
>   Das Kind ist ein- ganz l/Liebe**s** und /Nette**s**.

Comment: hm... auf der einen Seiten würde ich durchaus substantivierte Adjekte erkennen, auf der anderen Seite kommt mir die kleingeschriebene Variante richtig vor.. vielleicht da das Wörtchen "ist" im Spiel ist? Spannend :)

Comment: Mir kommt auch die klein geschriebene Variante richtig vor. Sprich in dem Sinn, dass damit die "liebe Hanni" bzw. die "nette Hanni" gemeint ist.

Comment: Oder eine bessere Begründung: Der Nebensatz ist eigenlich die Kurzform von "...dann ist die Hanni eh eine ganz liebe und nette Frau."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sie ist eine ganz **Liebe** und **Nette**.

Der Gebrauch des unbestimmten Artikels lässt nur Großschreibung zu. Wie nominalisierte Verben sind auch nominalisierte Adjektive groß zu schreiben.

Comment: Ah! Jetzt sehe ich es! Ich habe einen Gleichsetzungsnominativ, und das »Nominativobjekt« ist »eine ganz Liebe und Nette«, also nominalisierte Adjektive.